# Creating new rows by combining existing rows excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new here, so if this go against the rules please tell me.

I have an issue that seems pretty simple but I wanted to check to make sure. I have been trying to see if I could create a new row by combining every variable from one column with another, like so:

```
 Column 1       Column 2        Combined 
    A               1              A1
    B               2              A2
                    3              A3
                                   B1
                                   B2
                                   B3
```

But instead of typing the combinations manually, I wanted the combined column make this combination without user input and to update automatically whenever column 1 or 2 has a row added or removed. I have been trying to figure out if there is some way to use the concatenate function in excel or the & sign but neither methods seems to work. I was thinking trying to code this in visual basics.

The main question: is this possible to do in excel? If so which function(s) could I use?

Comment: The columns are messed up.

Comment: sarcastic comment: "Yes"

Comment: is column 2 always numbers?  Does it have a header row?  is 1,2,3 the only information in column 2 (likewise for column 1)?

Comment: Hey Ed! The actual columns will both be scripts, both should have header rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes your data has one header row (row 1), Column 1 is column 'A' and Column 2 is Column 'B'.  Place the formula below in an empty cell and copy down as far as your data permits.

```
 =INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW(A2)+1)/(COUNTA(B:B)-1))+1)&INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW(A2)-2,3)+1+1)
```

now if you want to add a little flag to let you know you have more row than you need for your data you could add the following:

```
 =IF(ROW(A2)-1>(COUNTA(A:A)-1)*(COUNTA(B:B)-1),"Data Exceeded",INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW(A2)+1)/(COUNTA(B:B)-1))+1)&INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW(A2)-2,3)+1+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

According to: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3097-excel-list-all-possible-combinations.html

You can use this formula:

> `=IF(ROW()-ROW(**$D$1**)+1>COUNTA(**$A$1:$A$4**)*COUNTA(**$B$1:$B$3**),"",INDEX(**$A$1:$A$4**,INT((ROW()-ROW(**$D$1**))/COUNTA(**$B$1:$B$3**)+1))&INDEX(**$B$1:$B$3**,MOD(ROW()-ROW($D$1),COUNTA(**$B$1:$B$3**))+1))`
>
> In the above formula, **$A$1:$A$4**, are the first column values, and
>   **$B$1:$B$3** are the second list values which you want to list all their
>   possible combinations, the **$D$1** is the cell that you put the formula,
>   you can change the cell references to your need.

In your case, you should use:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($C$2)+1>COUNTA($A$2:$A$3)*COUNTA($B$2:$B$4),"",INDEX($A$2:$A$3,INT((ROW()-ROW($C$2))/COUNTA($B$2:$B$4)+1))&INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MOD(ROW()-ROW($C$2),COUNTA($B$2:$B$4))+1))
```